# getting permission excheption at Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem)

Tags: c#, outlook

I want to open outlook 2010 for creating a new message , but I get the following exception.
I use visual studio 2012 , on windows server 2008 R2 standard , 64-bit operating system.

This is my code:

```
private void SendMail()
{
    try
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application =
            new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem =
            application.CreateItem(
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;

        mailItem.To = "someone@example.com";
        mailItem.Subject = "my subject";
        mailItem.Body = "message body";
        mailItem.Display();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was caught HResult=-2147287035
  Message=you do not have appropriate permission to perform this operation.
  Source=Microsoft Outlook
  ErrorCode=-2147287035
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass.CreateItem(OlItemType ItemType)
```